# Linear Discriminant Analysis (LDA) , Removing colinear features in cross validation set up is correct or not?

Tags: machine-learning

My data is a matrix with 725 features and 667 observations which have binary data(either 0 or 1). my target variable is a univariate which has two classes (either 0 or 1). I removed the features which had zero as column sums, so features reduced to 652. since I have a binary data I did not do the preprocessing (Mean = 0 and s.d=1). But, My data is highly sparse; there is 99% sparsity. If I want to use LDA model in a 10 c.v setup. Then I am required to remove the colinear features (this means that all the features in a training set whose column sum is zero should be removed) to predict small set of test data in every fold. If this is the case then in every fold I will have to remove a different set of features which are zero in that training set for the test set. Is it an acceptable practice to complete my y.predict after 10 c.v (each fold used different features to predict the y) and do a rowmean for all the folds in the end and then show the accuracy of a classifier? I cant have the correct feature selection from this strategy but I can get a classifier prediction performance.

Comment: What is LDA here?

Comment: LDA stands for Linear Discriminant Analysis, a supervised machine learning method. It can be used as a classifier. It also performs as a dimensionality reduction strategy as PCA. LDA preserves the between group variance but PCA preserves variance in data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The colinear features from the training set should be removed and same features should be removed from the test set. The features which are constant in a column are removed as a standard preprocessing technique. This is one possible work around. Improving the predictive performance of the classifier is the priority and feature selection is a different issue.